# fade in/fade out array loop stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can I stop this loop?

```
<body>
        <div class="container">

            <div id="claim"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          var classes = [
                '<h1 >Software</h1>',
                '<h1 >project </h1>',
                '<h1 >Engineering</h1>',  
                '<h1 >Science</h1>',
                '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png">'
            ];

            var i = 0;
            $("#claim").html(classes[i]);
            setInterval(function() {

                i = (i + 1) % classes.length;
                $("#claim").html(classes[i]);

            },  800);


        </script>
    </body>
```

the script works correctly, but I would like to stop it at the end.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clearInterval` function to stop this.

```
<script>
          var classes = [
                '<h1 >Software</h1>',
                '<h1 >project </h1>',
                '<h1 >Engineering</h1>',  
                '<h1 >Science</h1>',
                '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png">'
            ];

            var i = 0;
            var intervalId = null;
            $("#claim").html(classes[i]);
            var funcName = function() {
                i = (i + 1) % classes.length;
                $("#claim").html(classes[i]);
                if(classes.length == i + 1) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                }

            };
            intervalId = setInterval(funcName,  800);


        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) that cancels a timed, repeating action which was previously established by a call to `setInterval()`.

```js
var classes = [
    '<h1 >Software</h1>',
    '<h1 >project </h1>',
    '<h1 >Engineering</h1>',  
    '<h1 >Science</h1>',
    '<img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png">'
];

var i = 0;
$("#claim").html(classes[i]);

var interval = setInterval(function() {       
  if(i == classes.length - 2){ // stop at the end item
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  i = (i + 1) % classes.length;
  $("#claim").html(classes[i]);

},  800);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="claim"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```